# Horizontal 90 from p trap into wall

Tags: plumbing

Can I use this 1.5" 90 elbow between the P trap from the garbage disposal in the wall drain. Attached picture is taken from below.[image]

Comment: If we're looking from below, that is no problem at all, assuming the wall stub is lower than the disposal outlet.  Your pipe into the stub elbow looks kinda crooked though—but it could just be a photo perspective issue.

Comment: That was just a dry fit so pipes were a little crooked. I found that you have to use a long sweep 90 when using horizontal. I was able to cut back the pipe and fit in long sweep.